# Can I use modernizr to load background css images conditionally?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, modernizr

I want to have different sized images on different device widths, and sometimes no images at all in order to save mobile users bandwidth.

Will it work like intended like this:

```
Modernizr.load([{
    test: 1025 > window.screen.width, 
  yep: "mobile.css", 
  nope: "desktop.css" 
}]);
```

I have also discovered the following pure css solution, which allegedly works and will only load the images if required:

```
<div id="test3">
    <div></div>
</div>
#test3 div {
    background-image:url('images/test3.png');
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    #test3 {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

or

```
<div id="test5"></div>
@media all and (min-width: 601px) {
    #test5 {
        background-image:url('images/test5-desktop.png');
        width:200px;
        height:75px;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    #test5 {
        background-image:url('images/test5-mobile.png');
        width:200px;
        height:75px;
    }
}
```

source of this solution:
http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

But its rather complicated.

Is it a good idea to simply use modernizr to load all css which sets background images instead as to not load multiple image versions?

Comment: You should use media queries.

Comment: The logical response would be to google *media queries* to see what they're all about.

Comment: this is about loading images, i know well what media queries are about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly, Yes, it will work in the way you've outlined.

**Modernizr**

You can use Modernizr to load javascript and CSS, but also use the [`Modernizr.mq()`](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq) method to match media queries specifically. Example:

```
Modernizr.load([{

    // Test if media query matches
    test : Modernizr.mq('only screen and (max-width: 600px)'),

    // load css and js purely for mobile
    yep: ['/assets/mobile.css', '/assets/mobile.js']

  }]);
```

If you have two media queries (desktop and mobile), then you'd just test for both and load the required assets --or-- alter the above to include the following as it wouldn't match the test conditions:

```
    nope: ['/assets/desktop.css', '/assets/desktop.js']
```

Using modernizr (or any other asset-loader for that matter) to fullfil **all JS/CSS** asset loading is a decision that can only be made by you and with knowledge of:

- How complex your app is.
- How many assets(images, scripts, functions etc) are required.
- The level of sophistication/interactivity
- What you will save if you use modernizr
- The intended usage of your app/site

**What's wrong with media queries?**

If your site/app footprint isn't that heavy, then there is nothing wrong with using media queries alone to adapt the layout (and more importantly the experience) for different device-types; In fact it's a simpler approach, less complicated and more in line with responsive-design theory.

[This is one example](http://cloudfour.com/) [No affiliation] of swapping out different images for different device-types. Just resize the browser and see how the images are loaded.

In terms of using media queries, simplistically, you could either:

Include your media queries in one stylesheet:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #test5 {
      background-image:url('images/mobile.png');
      width:200px;
      height:75px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    #test5 {
      background-image:url('images/desktop.png');
      width:200px;
      height:75px;
  }
}
```

Or, link to separate CSS files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 601px)" href="desktop.css" />
```

Or, using `@import`:

```
@import url(mobile.css) (max-width:600px);
@import url(desktop.css) (min-width:601px);
```

You can see a simple example of `@import` in action [here](http://philarcher.org/diary/2011/importrules/).

**Other methods**

There are other, more sophisticated methods that use evenListeners to listen for changes in screen-width that will load/unload scripts based upon query state changes, but for the vast majority of projects, they are overkill.

Comment: thx, I think ill use the media queries and have ie conditional css for ie8

Comment: I think that's probably the simplest approach and one which has been already established as a convention :)

Comment: the problem is, as evident from the link in my question, mobile browsers may download all css and background images even if its for a different device per media query, unless you use media queries in a very specific way. Even then some browsers, like fennec, will still download everything. I wonder if the import solution works like that. Guess Ill try and test it.